# Clear up PyO3 removed Rust module?

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

I'm a bit puzzled: I had a PyO3 module which I've now removed completely... the Rust module directory and files have been deleted and there is no reference to them in any Cargo.toml files, or anywhere.

And yet, when I run my Python script it is still able to import the old Rust module, and run the PyO3 function which was in there.

I've tried `Cargo clean` but this doesn't seem to remove it. Obviously that's a Cargo-specific command, whereas what I really need is a PyO3-specific "clean" method.

I want Python to complain when I go `import my_old_rust_module` that the module can't be found.

Comment: Perhaps you installed this module? Try with `pip uninstall my_old_rust_module`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Now I'm wondering whether I actually consciously did `pip install my_old_rust_module` at some point previously (which I don't remember), or whether PyO3 does this behind the scenes... will go back and look at my PyO3 usage notes.

Comment: Seemingly not... so it would appear that `maturin develop` just does `pip install  my_rust_module` as one of its actions.